# How to get the list of my bank related of Credit and Debit cards added to Apple Wallet.

Tags: objective-c, ios11, credit-card, applepay, wallet

In In-App Provisioning how to get the added my bank related cards list from my banking application? Is it possible? If possible can anyone share you the code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

NSArray *passes = [[[PKPassLibrary alloc] init] passes]; will return all payment passes from your bank. But you have to do the below requirements:-

1. Enable Wallet capability for your app id
2. Add pass types added in the developer portal to your entitlement file
3. Use the updated profile with this entitlement

Comment: Hi Rajesh, tried this but getting an empty array in wallet card is available also.

Comment: Are you getting any error like "Missing entitlements" in your console logs? If yes, did you get entitlements for push provisioning from Apple? If yes, you need to add entitlements to your profile.

Comment: No I’m not getting anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your PNO (payment network operator - MasterCard, for example) has to correctly configure the card when the backends communicate with Apple.
They can specify App IDs that have access to the payment passes (these are not usual `PKPass`es) and App IDs that the card can open from the detail.

So there's not much you can do about it on the client side. You should be able to get all associated cards through `PKPassLibrary`'s `passes()` method, when your backend is set up correctly.

Comment: If you have time, would you describe what all you did? Cheers.

Comment: hi its a huge process from Getting the documentation from apple to Apple pay integration and testing by Apple team. Its better to start the process. If you struck any where please write will help u.

Comment: I'm actually approaching the finish line of the process too, it's all clear now. I was curious about your experience only .)

Comment: I faced a lot of difficulties while developing this We sent almost 2 months from getting Documentation from the Apple team to Apple Certification for this Card Provisioning. Finally, we did that. it was challenging in each and every step :). @Zoltán

Comment: Hey @Zoltán, I have a question about PNO. I just started reading the documentation, and it is written that PNO should configure some data. And I couldn't find what PNO is. In your comment, you have mentioned that MasterCard is an example of PNO. Does it mean that if I want both MasterCard and Visa cards to be added to wallet, I should contact both and tell them to add the configuration to their API?

Comment: Yes, you have to have a close cooperation with your PNOs, you can't get Apple Pay up and running without them.

Comment: The PNOs surely have experience with sll this. In our case we got from them a large spreadsheet that we had to fill in (it contained a lot of metadata, icons, card designs, app bundle IDs, etc) and they use that data in communication with Apple and eventually ends up in the client's phones.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. One more thing, I have sent Entitlement & Whitelisting Request to the given email about 5 days ago (2+ business days). But there is no response. Do they send any response at all? Should I keep sending emails till I receive one?

Comment: We waited longer, definitely don't expect a quick response. One case I know about (tho that was Apple Car entitlement) took 2 months to get an answer for. In our case was about one month, I think. Did you get the documentation for Apple Pay? Several PDF files explaining the flow, they're very helpful.

Comment: I just have 1 pdf file named 'in app provisioning, verification & security (v3.0)'. How many files are there?

Comment: We had 3 or 4 documents

Comment: Maybe apple will send the rest later. Or they have already sent it to someone else. I am not sure about that tbh.